# Delphi XE2 can not load CnPack

Tags: delphi

I have a fresh win 10 installation with Delphi XE2.

I tried to install CnPack but there was no chance (It says couldn't find wizard):
[image]

Also registry is OK and the file is in there and the permissions are OK.
[image]

Its version is CnWizards_1.1.3.896 which is currently the latest version.

I have tried older versions as well but there was no chance.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you ask first in the [CnWizards forum](http://bbs.cnpack.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=25)? A third-party tool's support forum should be your first effort, and I don't see any questions there about this issue. We're not the first line of support for their tools.

Comment: @KenWhite I couldn't register in their forums. It says we have sent activation email but nothing being sent. Also it doesn't resend it until 24 hours pass from the first one. And you cant ask questions before activation.

Comment: I removed a previous comment because I found where it says you have to wait 24 hours, so my comment was wrong. I'd suspect the problem is the account you used when you installed, though; are you running the IDE using the same account you used when installing CnWizards? (Are you logged in as the same user you were logged in when installing?) I'm using the same version of CnWizards without a problem in multiple IDE versions.

Comment: @KenWhite I ran the CnPack setup AsAdministrator to make sure it has every permission necessary. And I run Delphi AsAdministrator as well. So I think in terms of permission everything is in there. I have used CnPack on my previous laptop without any problem I don't know what is wrong with this CnPack installation. The previous laptop was win 10 and XE2 as well but hadn't this problem. Does Delphi has a log file so that we can see what is happening at startup?

Comment: No, there's no way to get a log file of startup.

Comment: Take it up with the vendor.

Comment: I installed the same package a few hours ago, XE2 on Windows 10. Worked fine. Are you really sure the file is where it should be?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes I checked it by issuing a DIR command and copy pasting the address from the error dialog. I also tried different drives even a folder in the root directory. Its very sad that Delphi doesn't have any log for startup.

Comment: @SpongebobComrade: Rather than using DIR, try a search tool like [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) (free, AFAIK written in Delphi or C++Builder).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis When it is in there whats the point in searching again with another tool? I can see the file is sitting there in many ways. So the problem is either Delphi or CnPack.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I got it to resolve to do this.

I downloaded the Source file and the Installer file.

I used this version 1.1.3.896.

First I open the source in Delphi and Compile, Build and Install the following components.

1. CnPack_DXE2.dpk.  (Compile and Build)
2. CnWizards_DXE2.dpr (Compile and Build)
3. dclCnPack_DXE2.dpk (Compile, Build and Install)
4. Execute the Installer file.

Now, this is the secret for me.

Replaced the files (CnWizards_DXE2.dll).

In the Third Step, it creates CnWizards_DXE2.dll (CnWizards\bin). Copy this file and paste in the local installation ([program files\CnPack\CnWizards]).

I created the mini tutorial in Portuguese for this situation, if necessary I can send it for you.

Sorry, my English is not good.

Bye for now

Comment: Worked for me! Using installer CnWizards_1.1.8.980.exe and source cnwizards_1.1.8.980_src. (Também sou brasileiro!)